# can we use Intent extras to preserve UI ?

Tags: android, user-interface, configuration

I was reading about different methods used to preserve UI data across configuration changes and system-initiated process death. i came across this paragraph that i coundn't understanad.

can anyone explain?

> Additionally, when you open an activity from an intent, the bundle of extras is delivered to the activity both when the configuration changes and when the system restores the activity. If a piece of UI state data, such as a search query, were passed in as an intent extra when the activity was launched, you could use the extras bundle instead of the onSaveInstanceState() bundle.

Link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: they dont say about `Intent`s extras at all - they mean `Bundle savedInstanceState` passed to `Activity#onCreate` method

Comment: This new stackoverflow user has posted a polite, clearly written question highlighting the exact paragraph of the official android developer documentation they don't quite understand. I'm disappointed that other users have downvoted this to -3! This is supposed to be a supportive forum for all regardless of current skill level. I've upvoted in the hope that @ahmed dahy is not discouraged from continuing to use stackoverflow to learn and improve their coding skills. I hope others will upvote too.

Comment: @SoundConception Thank you very much for your support. It's just like you said, people should realize that knowledge can not be gained at once. it is absolutely not a matter of transferring some data from one storage device to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they are saying is that when an Activity is restored after "configuration changes" or "system-initiated process death" you have multiple sources you can use to retrieve data from to get it setup as it was before e.g.:

1. Whatever was stored in the `savedInstanceState` bundle just before the Activity was killed.
2. Whatever was stored in the `Intent` that was used to start the Activity in the first place.  This same `Intent` is still available after an activity is killed and
   restored.

For example say you had a `UserProfile` Activity that showed information about the current user. When you launch the `UserProfileActivity` from some other activity, you could include information about the user in the `Intent`:

```
// Create Intent to start the `UserProfileActivity`
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserProfileActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("first_name", "John");
intent.putExtra("last_name", "Doe");

// Launch the intent
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the `UserProfileActivity` you can retrieve that info:

```
// Get the intent that was used to launch this activity
final Intent = getIntent();

// Get the required info from the intent
final String firstName = intent.getStringExtra("first_name");
final String lastName = intent.getStringExtra("last_name");

// Update the UI
TextView tvName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
tvName.setText(firstName + " " + lastName);
```

Now say the the `UserProfileActivity` had an *"About You"* EditText field and a *"Save"* button which will store the contents of the EditText in their profile.
The user is part way through writing stuff in the *"About You"* EditText when they decide to rotate the screen. The activity gets killed but they haven't hit the *"Save"* button yet! All the stuff they wrote gets lost = unhappy user!

How can we create a better user experience? When the `UserProfileActivity` is about to get killed, `onSaveInstanceState()` will get call, so save the current contents of the *"About You"* EditText in the `savedInstanceState` bundle, and restore it once the activity is recreated.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    // Store relevant state variables
    final EditText etAboutYou = findViewById(R.id.aboutYou);
    outState.putString("about_you", etAboutYou.getText().toString());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    // Restore saved state if required
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        final String aboutYou = savedInstanceState.getString("about_you");
        final EditText etAboutYou = findViewById(R.id.aboutYou);
        etAboutYou.setText(aboutYou);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly the explanation i needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: For others to benefit also, the reason i asked about this is that i did not understand why Intent( used to create new activity) is brought in the context of saving an activity status to be restored after a configuration change or a system-initiated process death. Mr @Sound Conception elegant answer explained that.